# JFileChooser set multi selection mode

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am attempting to use a `JFileChooser` to select multiple files. I know I can `setMultiSelectionEnabled(true)` but this selects all the files between the first file clicked and the second. Is there a way to make it only select the files that are clicked? I am looking for something similar to the [`MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection) in `JList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by holding Control (Ctrl) button while clicking the selections. The selection behaviour is standard behaviour and cannot be controlled programmatically.

Comment: Is there a way to make it always enabled? Can I do it if I extend the `JFileChooser` class or another class?

Comment: I am not sure but may be you can do something by extending `WindowsFileChooser` class. However, I believe, it will be very confusing to the end user. For example, suppose I clicked on File A. Now I don't want that file and instead I want File X, then on clicking File X, it will make both File A and File X as selected, which is obviously what the user didn't want. Or is there something that I completely misunderstood?

Comment: Mainly, I was curious if I could do it. I was thinking of leaving either an option for the user or not doing it at all (I am the intended user).